# How to solve when query returning no result when the transactionDate is called in symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am currently working on a project using symfony2. I am doing a serach function for my project and I encounter this problem.Having a multiple condition in my WHERE statement. The first condition work fine but the next is not. Here is my code for WHERE statement:

```
WHERE (a.refNumber LIKE :refNumber OR a.poNumber LIKE :refNumber 
              OR a.invoiceNumber LIKE :refNumber 
              OR a.asnNumber LIKE :refNumber 
              OR a.adjNumber LIKE :refNumber )
        AND b.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber
        AND b.senderId LIKE :senderId
        AND b.receiverId LIKE :receiverId
        AND c.docType LIKE :docType
        AND c.direction LIKE :direction
        AND (b.transactionDate <= :startDate AND b.transactionDate >= :endDate)

        ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc
```

Explaination :

My `refNumber` can be a `poNumber, invNumber, asnNumber or adjNumber`.It can search either of them. `GsNumber` on the other hand can be left blank. It can just be use for a specified docType.

> `DocType` must not be leave blank whatever you search.

In regards with the transaction date, it must search any transaction that belongs to the query of start date and end date. sadly, it is not working, I cannot get the date. `Start date` must be greater than or equal to the transaction date.`End date` must be less than or equal sa transction date. It must return the  transactions that belongs to that query. But then again, it is not working , it returns blank . But if I remove the startdate and the enddate everything works perfectly. I don't know what to do anymore.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search parameters are optional, you need make the tests that use that parameter succeed when it's empty.

```
WHERE (:refNumber = '' OR a.refNumber LIKE :refNumber OR a.poNumber LIKE :refNumber 
       OR a.invoiceNumber LIKE :refNumber 
       OR a.asnNumber LIKE :refNumber 
       OR a.adjNumber LIKE :refNumber )
   AND (:gsNumber = '' OR b.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber)
   AND (:senderId = '' OR b.senderId LIKE :senderId)
   AND (:receiverId = '' OR b.receiverId LIKE :receiverId)
   AND (:docType = '' OR c.docType LIKE :docType)
   AND (:direction = '' OR c.direction LIKE :direction)
   AND (:startDate = '' OR :endDate = '' OR b.transactionDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)
```

The more common way to deal with this is to build the `WHERE` clause dynamically, so you don't put the `gsNumber` test in if that search field is empty. See [Search Form with One or More (Multiple) Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909705/search-form-with-one-or-more-multiple-parameters/28909923#28909923)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85327/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-how-to-solve-when-query-returning-no-result-when).

Answer (score 0):

In your original query, your `:startDate` and `:endDate` were transposed.

`BETWEEN` is definitely the better method here, but in your update query, the syntax was off.  Change it to :

```
WHERE (a.refNumber LIKE :refNumber OR a.poNumber LIKE :refNumber 
                  OR a.invoiceNumber LIKE :refNumber 
                  OR a.asnNumber LIKE :refNumber 
                  OR a.adjNumber LIKE :refNumber )
            AND b.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber
            AND b.senderId LIKE :senderId
            AND b.receiverId LIKE :receiverId
            AND c.docType LIKE :docType
            AND c.direction LIKE :direction
            AND b.transactionDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate

            ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc
```

Comment: thanks trex005 , but I got this error : Error: Expected Literal, got 'BETWEEN', how can I to solve this?

Comment: What on earth?  Somehow it must have posted mid formatting.  Try it again now.

Comment: I got no error, but it display nothing even though I haven't started searching as in, all the data to display before searching are all gone.:(