# serialise form with dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have created a `for` loop that allows me to produce textboxes for a user to input data to add to a mySql database.

```js
var $frm2 = $("<form id=insertform class=form2></form>"); // craete the form
$frm2.append(txt8, txt9); // add 2 clone dropdown boxes to the form

// this loop creates n number of text boxes abnd adds them to the form 
for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  { 
    $('<input /></br>', {
        id: "valueid" + i,
        text: "text",
        name: "user"
    }).appendTo($frm2);
}
```

The problem is when I serialise the data to AJAX post via JSON only the two drop boxes are serialised, the textboxes don't seem to add to the data.

```js
$("#inserthbtn").click(function() {
    var datastring = $($frm2).serialize();
    $("#reports4").append(datastring);
    alert(datastring);
});
```

[image]

If u can see where I'm going wrong that would be amazing (I also know I am missing the script to post to AJAX, I couldn't get this to work so removed as part of fault finding process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the inputs array-style names ending in `[]`. When it's serialized, they will be collected into an array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
{   
        $('<input />', {id: "valueid" + i,text: "text",name: "user[]"}).appendTo($frm2);
        $('<br />').appendTo($frm2);    
}
```

Also, you can't use the object argument to `$()` to specify attributes of the new element when you put multiple elements into the first argument.

Another option is to give them unique names, `name: "user"+i`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much, I went with ' name: "user"+i', that will help with the php alot. thanks again so much

Comment: If you're using PHP, I'd go with `user[]`. Then `$_POST['user']` will be an array that you can easily loop over with `foreach`.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I actually have to do this by creating a prepared statement in a PDO, first time trying to do this, any pointer towards literature that will help?, u dont have to do this if you dont have time mate you have been more than helpful thanks so much again

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909705/search-form-with-one-or-more-multiple-parameters/28909923#28909923) for how to create a prepared statement dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because although you provide an object with the properties to apply to the `input` you dynamically create, you're creating two elements (the `input` and `br`) therefore jQuery isn't sure which element you want to put the properties on. Remove the `br` element from the selector and it will work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  { 
    $('<input />', {
        id: "valueid" + i,
        text: "text",
        name: "user"
    }).appendTo($frm2);
}
```

Comment: This still has the serialization problem because of the duplicate names.