# Use PHP in Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a very noobish question right here. How can I use PHP in my PHP SQL query?

My query is

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE categorie='4' AND actief='1' ORDER BY prijs + 0 ASC");
```

and what I'm trying to have is this

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE categorie='4' AND ". if(htmlentities($gegevens['rang']) == '1') { echo ""; } else { echo "actief='1'";} . " ORDER BY prijs + 0 ASC");
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `?:` conditional (AKA [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)) expression.

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE categorie='4' ". ($gegevens['rang'] == '1' ? "" : "AND actief='1'") . " ORDER BY prijs + 0 ASC");
```

And the `AND` should be part of the string that's added by the conditional code. Otherwise, when `$gegevens['rang']` is not `1`, you'll have `AND` with no condition after it.

For a more general approach to building the `WHERE` clause dynamically, see

[Search Form with One or More (Multiple) Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909705/search-form-with-one-or-more-multiple-parameters/28909923#28909923)

Comment: Hello Barmar, when I'm working with your code it give me an error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY prijs + 0 ASC' at line 1"

Comment: The AND should be in the conditional ;)

Comment: `mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE categorie='4' ". ($gegevens['rang'] == '1' ? "" : " AND actief='1'") . " ORDER BY prijs + 0 ASC");`

Answer (score 1):

For everyone's sanity, please do not use ternary conditions inside SQL string concatenation.

```
$andActeif = "";
if (intval($gegevens['rang']) == 1) {
    $andActive = " AND acteif = '1' ";
}
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "
   SELECT * 
   FROM shop
   WHERE categorie='4'
   $andActeif
   ORDER BY prijs + 0 ASC");
```

Your future self will thank you.