# Passing query strings to a PDO sql query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a custom endpoint for returning JSON based on different SQL queries - the queries are created based on multiple query strings I am passing from my App. What I've done is shabby and would like to know if there is a better way of achieving the same results as what the below returns:

The below is just a small selection of all the IF/Else statements checking for different query strings

```
if(isset($_GET['pt']) && !isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['sc']) && isset($_GET['size'])) {

    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM product
    INNER JOIN product_sizes
    ON product.product_sku = product_sizes.affiliate_p_id
    WHERE product_sizes.product_type IN (".$_GET['pt'].") 
    AND product_sizes.product_sizes IN (".$_GET['size'].") 
    GROUP BY product_sizes.affiliate_p_id
    ORDER BY product.last_updated ASC
    LIMIT 100";


} else {

    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM product
    INNER JOIN product_sizes
    ON product.product_sku = product_sizes.affiliate_p_id
    GROUP BY product_sizes.affiliate_p_id
    ORDER BY product.last_updated ASC
    LIMIT 100";

}


$result = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$return = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $return[] = array( 
        'affiliate_p_id' => $row['affiliate_p_id'],
        'affiliate_id' => $row['affiliate_id'],
        'product_colours' => $row['product_colours'],
        'product_sub_category' => $row['product_sub_category'],
        'merchant_name' => $row['merchant_name'],
        'product_type' => $row['product_type'],
        'product_sizes' => $row['product_sizes'],
        'product_name' => $row['product_name'],
        'sale_price' => $row['sale_price'],
        'rrp_price' => $row['rrp_price'],
        'product_image' => $row['product_image'],
        'product_slug' => $row['product_slug']          
    );
}
$dbh = null;    

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Your code is already running as expected? You just want to discuss if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Yep exactly! It looks clunky and would know if there is a much better way

Comment: This kind of question should be typical for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and somehow offtopic on SO

Comment: Use the where statement inside a variable, and just add that variable if the condition satisfies. you can use something like $sql .= $where . So break your codes into smaller parts and combine it based on conditions.

Comment: @DanWhiteside your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, never add untrusted data to the query string. Both queries are quite similiar, you'd be much better off using the same query and conditionally adding the where condition(s) if params are submitted.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for an example of how to build the `WHERE` clause dynamically. And one of the big benefits of using PDO is using prepared statements instead of substituting variables directly into the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break it into smaller parts like this

```html
$sql = 'SELECT *
    FROM product
    INNER JOIN product_sizes
    ON product.product_sku = product_sizes.affiliate_p_id ';
if(isset($_GET['pt']) && !isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['sc']) && isset($_GET['size'])) {
$sql .= 
    " WHERE product_sizes.product_type IN :pt AND product_sizes.product_sizes IN  = :size ';
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY product_sizes.affiliate_p_id
    ORDER BY product.last_updated ASC
    LIMIT 100";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
if(isset($_GET['pt']) && !isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['sc']) && isset($_GET['size'])) {
$sth->execute(array(':pt' => $_GET['pt'], ':size' => $_GET['size']));
}
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could refactor it a bit to dinamically build the sql string.

```
// SQL start common to all queries
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM product 
        INNER JOIN product_sizes 
        ON product.product_sku = product_sizes.affiliate_p_id";

// Append query depending on conditions
if(isset($_GET['pt']) && !isset($_GET['c']) && !isset($_GET['sc']) && isset($_GET['size'])) {
    $sql .= " WHERE product_sizes.product_type IN (".$_GET['pt'].") 
              AND product_sizes.product_sizes IN (".$_GET['size'].")";
}

// SQL end common to all queries
$sql .= " GROUP BY product_sizes.affiliate_p_id
          ORDER BY product.last_updated ASC
          LIMIT 100";
```

This way you don't repeat SQL parts that are common to all queries.

Comment: Oh I really like this concept! I will also look into what @Amit Ray said about the sql injections - as this app is in early stages I am just concepting and will ensure this won't reach it to live build

Comment: @DanWhiteside Definitely you need to fix sql injections. Prepared statements is your best bet.