# How to Select records with over 4 criteria

Tags: mysql, vb.net, select

Select records based on the criteria shown

[image]

Is there any way i can select records from MySQL based on this criteria apart using the many if else statements.
Actually what i have in mind is below

```
if CurrentLevel.SelectedItem <> Nothing AND Programme.SelectedItem = Nothing AND Gender.SelectedItem = Nothing Then

myconnection.Open()
Dim SelCmd as SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * From StudentsList Where CurrentLevel = '"& CurrentLevel.SelectedItem &"'",myconnection)
```

And I'll have to do it for all the possible outcomes.
Which makes the code very lengthy and tiresome to write.

Is there a shorter way of performing this search because I'll perform another search with almost 16 criteria.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for how to build the `WHERE` clause dynamically in PHP. You should be able to do something similar in VB, but I don't know that language.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear to me. You won't need a new if statement for all the criteria. You can achieve this by modifying the SQL query itself. One of the main purpose of SQL is to get data that match certain criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM StudentsList WHERE `CurrentLevel` = "level" AND `gender` = "male" AND `programme` = "something"
```

The above SQL query should give you a basic idea. It will select the rows which have CurrentLevel as level, gender as male and programme as something only, the rest will be ignored.

**EDIT:**

I don't know VB. Here is a quick, dirty example in C# which will help you understand the basic logic behind this.

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM StudentsList ";
if(currentLevelDropDown.SelectedItem.Text != "") 
{
    sqlQuery + "WHERE CurrentLevel = " + currentLevelDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
}

if(ProgrammeDropDown.SelectedItem.Text != "")
{
    sqlQuery + " AND WHERE programme = " + ProgrammeDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
}

//Final Query becomes: SELECT * FROM StudentsList WHERE CurrentLevel = userSelectedOption AND WHERE programme = userSelectedProgrammeOption

//Finally execute the sqlQuery
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer @praneeth. But I want to leave it open. So that the user can search with any criteria of his/her choice. The answer you gave is when all the conditions are true, i.e. when the user selects currentlevel and programme and gender, But what if the user doesn't select any level but select programme and gender.?

Comment: @VincentPrinceAssah in that case you will have to have if conditions for what to conditions to include in the query. For example, if the user left the CurrentLevel blank, then do not include it in the query.

Comment: That, I'm aware of. But that'll make the code lengthy because you'll have to have a query for each condition. What happens then when there are over 16 search criteria?

Comment: No, there will be only one SQL query. You will be deciding which conditions to be there and which shouldn't be. Will edit the original answer.

Comment: Can you please give an example with the picture I posted. @praneeth

Comment: @VincentPrinceAssah Edited the original answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @Praneeth. Can I please have your email address. I would like to have a chat with you. Please. Mine is prynx1@gmail.com