# Is there a variable for mysql that returns all?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `MySQL` query using a `WHERE` clause based on a variable. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to set the variable to something like a wildcard that would return any value in that field?

```
WHERE c.call_state_id = $state
AND  (follow_emp_id = $user_id OR follow_emp_id = 117)
ORDER BY $sort
```

Instead of limiting the results to 1 specific `$user_id`, I want to virtually eliminate the `AND` portion of the query.

Comment: @Siyual it's does not solve the problem

Comment: I understand that OP want such value for $user_id which return true for all follow_emp_id

Comment: `"WHERE c.call_state_id = $state" .
($user_id != "*" ? "AND  (follow_emp_id = $user_id OR follow_emp_id = 117) " : " ")  .
"ORDER BY $sort"`

Comment: @splash58 In that case, based on the sql-injection-prone state of the current query, all he would need to set `$user_id` to is the string: `follow_emp_id`.

Comment: @Siyual Yes. you right, i think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build the query dynamically, and check for the value before putting it into the `WHERE` clause.

```
if (empty($userid)) {
    $userid_check = ""
} else {
    $userid_check = "AND (follow_emp_id = $user_id OR follow_emp_id = 117)"
}
$sql = "SELECT ...
        WHERE c.call_state_id = $state
        $userid_check
        ORDER BY $sort";
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for a more general approach to building queries dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a value that will not be used, such as 0 (or -1); you can just check for that:

```
WHERE c.call_state_id = $state
AND  ($user_id = 0 OR follow_emp_id = $user_id OR follow_emp_id = 117)
ORDER BY $sort
```