# Ajax to Filter Results Without Reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have created a webpage with a details of products (15, 30 or 45 per page).
The user have the possibility to reorder by reviews, by price, etc. and can select the brands, the weight, etc.
I'm using Ajax to send the query to the external page.. This is dangerous?
What would be another way to make sure I do not get attacks?

Comment: Why do you think this is dangerous? As long as the server script checks that you're authorized, you should be OK. You can't prevent attacks, all you can do is make sure your do proper checks so the attacks won't be successful.

Comment: Because a visitor can modify the query by HTML.. Can take an UPDATE command or similar dangerous query

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were actually sending the SQL via AJAX. The proper way to do it is to send the search options, and build the query in PHP from them. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for example.

Answer (score 0):

From your API, make sure you're auditing the request coming from the client. Check for bounds, make sure it's not malformed, make sure it fits what you're expecting. If it's invalid, send back a proper response to the client stating so (403/404/etc)... if it's valid, then send back the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send raw SQL from the client. Just send the values of the form fields, and use them in the PHP script on the server to construct the SQL query.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for a technique to generate the `WHERE` clause dynamically from form fields. Similar methods can be used for the `ORDER BY` clause.