# Is there a wildcard operator for the MySql WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following MySql SELECT via PHP successfully returns rows containing a color specified by the variable `$my_color`.

```
$my_color = "red";
$a = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE color=:color");
$a->bindParam('color', $my_color);
$a->execute();
$data = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I would also like to perform searches that are not dependent on specific colors.  I can do this with an if-then block to use a different SELECT pattern but...

**Question:**  Does MySQL have the ability to set a WHERE condition to something that translates to "accept anything" (`WHERE = *`)?

Comment: `WHERE color LIKE '%%'` - `$my_color = "%%"`

Comment: why not just not use a where clause that will give you everything.  Or if you have to put in a where clause you can say where 1=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE` instead of `=`. If the value doesn't contain any wildcard characters, `LIKE` performs an exact equivalence check. But then you can use `%` as a wildcard to match anything. So:

```
$color = '%';
$a = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE color LIKE :color");
$a->bindParam('color', $my_color);
$a->execute();
$data = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, a better option might be to put the logic in PHP rather than SQL.

```
if ($color) {
    $a = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE color=:color");
    $a->bindParam('color', $my_color);
} else {
    $a = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table");
}
$a->execute();
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for a more general technique for building the `WHERE` clause dynamically from multiple form inputs.

Comment: I'm curious, why would handling it PHP side be a _better option_?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a LIKE clause with the input being a wildcard character like this:

```
$my_color = "%";
$a = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE color LIKE :color");
$a->bindParam('color', $my_color);
$a->execute();
$data = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[More Info on the LIKE clause](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_like_clause.htm)