# Get mysql json parameters in url

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

Im trying to retrieve data from mysql database and pass it through json, that the url will have certain parameters to show specific data. the link works it brings back the data but it doesn't brings back what i need.

**PHP CODE FOR "api.php?cat_id=1"**

```
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{
    $post_order_by=API_CAT_POST_ORDER_BY;

    $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];    

    $jsonObj= array();  

    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_wallpaper
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_wallpaper.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    where tbl_wallpaper.cat_id='".$cat_id."' ORDER BY tbl_wallpaper.id ".$post_order_by."";

    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $row['id'] = $data['id'];
        $row['cat_id'] = $data['cat_id'];
        $row['scat_name'] = $data['scat_name'];
        $row['wallpaper_image'] = $file_path.'categories/'.$data['cat_id'].'/'.$data['image'];
        $row['wallpaper_image_thumb'] = $file_path.'categories/'.$data['cat_id'].'/thumbs/'.$data['image']; 
        $row['total_views'] = $data['total_views'];

        $row['cid'] = $data['cid'];
        $row['category_name'] = $data['category_name'];
        $row['category_image'] = $file_path.'images/'.$data['category_image'];
        $row['category_image_thumb'] = $file_path.'images/thumbs/'.$data['category_image'];


        array_push($jsonObj,$row);

    }

    $set['HD_WALLPAPER'] = $jsonObj;

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    die();


}
```

**PHP CODE FOR "api.php?scat_name=9&cat_id=1"** i want this one to filter the result and only show the data share both scat_name and cat_id

```
  if(isset($_GET['scat_name'], $_GET['cat_id']))
 {
    $post_order_by=API_CAT_POST_ORDER_BY;

    $scat_id=$_GET['scat_name'];
    $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];


    $jsonObj= array();  

    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_wallpaper
    LEFT JOIN tbl_scategory ON tbl_wallpaper.scat_name = tbl_scategory.scid
    where tbl_wallpaper.scat_name='".$scat_id."' ORDER BY tbl_wallpaper.id ".$post_order_by."";



    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $row['id'] = $data['id'];
        $row['cat_id'] = $data['cat_id'];
        $row['scat_name'] = $data['scat_name'];
        $row['wallpaper_image'] = $file_path.'categories/'.$data['cat_id'].'/'.$data['image'];
        $row['wallpaper_image_thumb'] = $file_path.'categories/'.$data['cat_id'].'/thumbs/'.$data['image']; 
        $row['total_views'] = $data['total_views'];

        $row['cid'] = $data['cid'];
        $row['category_name'] = $data['category_name'];
        $row['category_image'] = $file_path.'images/'.$data['category_image'];
        $row['category_image_thumb'] = $file_path.'images/thumbs/'.$data['category_image'];


        array_push($jsonObj,$row);

    }

    $set['HD_WALLPAPER'] = $jsonObj;

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    die();


}
```

when i call the url i put it like for example "api.php?scat_name=9&cat_id=1" the result it gives me is based only on cat_id even though that i put anything that doesnt exist in the scat_name= it still works and brings back result based on cat_id. The result i get on the browser is like this: notice that scat_name 9 and 0 means doesnt rely on that bring the data base but only cat_id which 1.

```
{
        "id": "241",
        "cat_id": "1",
        "scat_name": "9",
        "wallpaper_image": "ut.jpg",
        "wallpaper_image_thumb": "ut.jpg",
        "total_views": "0",
        "cid": "1",
        "category_name": "test",
        "category_image": "yg9.png",
        "category_image_thumb": "qyg9.png"
    },
{
        "id": "231",
        "cat_id": "1",
        "scat_name": "0",
        "wallpaper_image": "s.jpg",
        "wallpaper_image_thumb": "s.jpg",
        "total_views": "2",
        "cid": "1",
        "category_name": "test",
        "category_image": "9.png",
        "category_image_thumb": "9.png"
    },
```

Comment: There's no reason to call `str_replace()` on the result of `json_encode()`. It returns valid JSON, you're probably messing it up by replacing things.

Comment: Your second query never uses `$cat_id`.

Comment: it doesnt matter for the str_replace to be called or not, it wont change anything. yes i know that i never used $cat_id but why when i call it on the url it only based cat_id and it doesnt use scat_name. and when make it like **if(isset($_GET['scat_name']))** and i call **"api.php?scat_name=9"** it shows results based on scatname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first block of code should use this test:

```
if (isset($_GET['cat_id']) && !isset($_GET['scat_name']))
```

Otherwise it will run when only the second block should run.

In the second query, you're only filtering on scat_name, not on `cat_id`.

You should also use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

```
$query="SELECT w.id, w.cat_id, w.scat_name, w.image, w.total_views,
                s.cid, s.category_name, s.category_image
    FROM tbl_wallpaper AS w
    LEFT JOIN tbl_scategory AS s ON w.scat_name = s.scid
    where w.scat_name=? AND w.cat_id = ?
    ORDER BY w.id ".$post_order_by;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $scat_id, $cat_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $cat_id, $scat_name, $image, $total_views, $cid, $category_name, $category_image);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch(stmt)) {
    $jsonObj[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'cat_id' => $cat_id,
        'scat_name' => $scat_name,
        'wallpaper_image' => $file_path.'categories/'.$cat_id.'/'.$image,
        'wallpaper_image_thumb' => $file_path.'categories/'.$cat_id.'/thumbs/'.$image,
        'total_views' => $total_views,
        'cid' => $cid,
        'category_name' => $category_name,
        'category_image' => $file_path.'images/'.$category_image,
        'category_image_thumb' => $file_path.'images/thumbs/'.$category_image
    );
}
```

If you want to be able to handle arbitrary combinations of filtering criteria, you should build the query dynamically. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for how to do it in PDO.

Comment: thank you for pointing out about the first block. i think the filtering way you proposed is too far, i guess theres an easy way

Comment: What's not easy about `WHERE scat_name = $scat_id AND cat_id = $cat_id`?

Comment: i tried to replace my code by the one provided it shows blank page, and theres an extra ' at the last line that it should be removed

Comment: it shows empty array like this {
    "HD_WALLPAPER": []
}

Comment: You accepted the answer, does that mean you solved the problem of the empty array?

Comment: yes i did , i got the hint from your answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing us two parts of a singe php (and since both are api.php, I guess you are), then yes, the program is working exactly as you designed it:

If `cat_id` is set in the URL, then it will execute the section where you test of `cat_id`, and it will not reach the area where you test of both.

If you want that section to be executed only when `scat_name` is *not* set, then test for that:

Change:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
```

for:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']) && !isset($_GET['scat_name']))
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out to that it executes it now but with blank page, i think because i missed up with part of of quering the data. what would be the way to get the filtered result upon executing scat_name&cat_id