# How can I set dynamic optional WHERE clauses into a SQL query? (if the value of the parameter is not null)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have a problem with a query. I am working on **MySql**.

I have this query that contains a single WHERE clause that is mandatory and some other WHERE clauses that are optional, something like this:

```
WHERE Localization.id = 2
AND(
    Crop.id = 2
    OR
    ProcessPhase.id = 1
    OR
    ProcessPhaseAction.id = 1
    OR
    UserType.id = 1
    OR
    Urgency.id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id = 1
    OR
    EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id = 1
    )
```

The **Localization.id** is the mandatory clause, the other into the **AND** are optional. I implemented in this way but I think that it is not good.

My original idea is that if the value of a field is null this specific where clause is deleted from the clauses list.

For example, I want to put all the clauses using the AND (avoiding the **OR**) and if I have something:

```
Crop.id = null
```

this clause it is removed from the clauses list.

I know that I can do it using a programming language appending the clauses with an IF statment ( IF is not null then append) but in this case this query will nor run into a program so I can't do it so I have to use only SQL.

How can I do it using only SQL?

**EDIT-1**:
This is the updated clauses version but it still not works:

```
WHERE Localization.id = 2

AND 
    (EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id IS NULL)
```

**EDIT-2**: this is the entire query:

```
SELECT 
    EnutrifoodMessage.content
    , MessageType.message_type_name
    , Country.country_name
    , IFNULL(Province.province_name, 'All Provinces') as province_name
    , IFNULL(District.district_name, 'Any District') as district_name
    , Crop.crop_name
    , EnutriMessageDetails.creation_date
    , EnutriMessageDetails.message_important_days
    , temp_scale.scale_name as temperature
    , humidity_scale.scale_name as humidity
    , ProcessPhase.phase_name
    , ProcessPhaseAction.process_phase_action_name
    , Urgency.urgency_name as action
    , IFNULL(MeteoWarningDescription.meteo_warning_description_name, '') as emergency
    , IFNULL(EnutriMessageDetails.internal_link, '') as internal_link
    , IFNULL(EnutriMessageDetails.reference_link, '') as reference_link
    , IFNULL(EnutriMessageDetails.external_link, '') as external_link
    , IFNULL(cleared_by_institution.institution_name, '') as message_cleared_by
    , UserType.user_type_name as end_user
    , provider.institution_name as provider
    , ValueAddition.value_addition_name
FROM EnutriMessageDetails
LEFT JOIN EnutrifoodMessage
ON EnutrifoodMessage.id = EnutriMessageDetails.enutri_food_message_id
LEFT JOIN MessageType
ON MessageType.id = EnutriMessageDetails.message_type_id
LEFT JOIN Localization
ON Localization.id = EnutriMessageDetails.localization_id
LEFT JOIN Country
ON Country.id = Localization.country_id
LEFT JOIN Province
ON Province.id = Localization.province_id
LEFT JOIN District
ON District.id = Localization.district_id
LEFT JOIN Crop
ON Crop.id = EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id
LEFT JOIN Scale temp_scale
ON temp_scale.id = EnutriMessageDetails.temp_scale_id
LEFT JOIN Scale humidity_scale
ON humidity_scale.id = EnutriMessageDetails.humidity_scale_id
LEFT JOIN ProcessPhase
ON ProcessPhase.id = EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id
LEFT JOIN ProcessPhaseAction
ON ProcessPhaseAction.id = EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id
LEFT JOIN Urgency
ON Urgency.id = EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id
LEFT JOIN MeteoWarningDescription
ON MeteoWarningDescription.id = EnutriMessageDetails.meteo_warning_description_id
LEFT JOIN Institution cleared_by_institution
ON cleared_by_institution.id = EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id
LEFT JOIN UserType
ON UserType.id = EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id
LEFT JOIN Institution provider
ON provider.id = EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id
LEFT JOIN ValueAddition
ON ValueAddition.id = EnutriMessageDetails.value_addition_id

WHERE Localization.id = 2

AND 
    (EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id IS NULL)
AND
    (EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id = 2 OR EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id IS NULL)

ORDER BY EnutrifoodMessage.id
```

Comment: Are you generating the SQL dynamically from a programming language like PHP? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895

Comment: @Barmar I explain that I can't do it because this query is not running into a program so it have to be done by SQL code

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
AND (Crop.id = 2 OR Crop.id IS NULL) AND ...
```

If `Crop.id` is `NULL` then the expression in the parenthesis is equal to 1 (true).

Comment: It seems can't work in this way and I can't understand wxactly why. I mean if the Crop.id as inserted INPUT PARAMETER is null and not if the value of the id field into the Crop table is null so the condition have to be deleted from the clauses list

Comment: @AndreaNobili Can you post the actual code you are using?

Comment: I updated my original post adding the required information at the end of my post. TNX

Comment: @AndreaNobili My request was about the *actual code* you have been using. Do you have a prepared statement? Do you have an SQL query inside a stored procedure?

Comment: I updated again my original post adding the entire query code. It is a simple SQL query. It have to be inserted into an ESB application to be performed. So it is not into a prepared statment or into a stored procedure. It is just performed as it is

Comment: @AndreaNobili I hoped your edit would help me understand what you mean by `if the Crop.id as inserted INPUT PARAMETER is null ...`. Unfortunately I'm still not able to understand ... is value `2` stored in a variable?