# When given is not filled in form fetch all content in the database

Tags: php, mysql

The form requests the e-mail (optional)

```
<select name="mail">
    <option value="gmail">@gmail</option>
</select>
```

and search the email that the user types

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

And I make the query in the database and one of the conditions is as follows:

```
AND mail = '$email'
```

However, this email may not be filled out on the form (not required)

How do I put in if it's empty add the wildcard and list all the emails?

I've tried something like:

```
<select name="mail">
    <option value="">ALL</option>
</select>
```

and

```
AND mail = '%$email'
```

But it did not work.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check if the value was passed and conditionally add the email constraint. If there's no value to test, that line doesn't need to be in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Create the query without this check in it, then add the check conditionally:

```
if (!empty($email)) {
    $query .= " AND mail = '$email';
}
```

However, you really should avoid substituting variables into SQL queries, because of SQL-injection, and instead use parametrized queries. See [Search Form with One or More (Multiple) Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909705/search-form-with-one-or-more-multiple-parameters/28909923#28909923) for a general method to build queries dynamically.