# Dynamic PDO bindParam function

Tags: php, pdo

I have a MySQL table (say it's called `cheeses` which contains a number of fields I want to search against.

A user enters a search string into the search field on the form, and when the form is submitted, I build an SQL statement using the fields.

For example, say the fields I am searching against are `unicode` and `name`.

If a user enters "blue cheese" I want to build an SQL statement which would go like this:

```
select name, unicode, description, id
from cheese
where 1 = 1
and (unicode like '%blue%' 
  or unicode like '%cheese%' 
  or name like '%blue%'
  or name like '%cheese%');
```

Apologies for the crappy logic and all the other rubbish things that smart people will see when they read through my basic requirements.

This is a basic run down of the code:

```
// get the search string and do something with it:
$str = $_POST['str'];
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $str);
$totalKeywords = count($keywords);

// build up the sql strings for unicode and name

// unicode
for($i=0 ; $i < $totalKeywords; $i++){
    $search_bit_unicode = ":search_unicode" . $i;
    if ($i == 0) {
        $sql_str_unicode .= " unicode LIKE $search_bit_unicode ";
    } else {
        $sql_str_unicode .= " OR unicode LIKE $search_bit_unicode ";
    }
}

// name
for($i=0 ; $i < $totalKeywords; $i++){
    $search_bit_name = ":search_name" . $i;
    $sql_str_name .= " OR name LIKE $search_bit_name ";
}

// ..... and then build in the bindParams for when the PDO code runs

// unicode
if (!empty($sql_str_unicode)) {
    $keywords_unicode = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $str);
    $totalKeywords_unicode = count($keywords_unicode);
    for ($x = 0; $x<$totalKeywords_unicode; $x++) {
    $keywords_unicode[$x] = "%" . $keywords_unicode[$x] . "%";
    $keywords_unicode[$x] = preg_replace('/@{2,}/','-',$keywords_unicode[$x]);
    $stmt2a->bindParam(':search_unicode' . $x, $keywords_unicode[$x]);
    }
}

// name
if (!empty($sql_str_name)) {
    $keywords_name = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $str);
    $totalKeywords_name = count($keywords_name);
    for ($y = 0; $y<$totalKeywords_name; $y++) {
    $keywords_name[$y] = "%" . $keywords_name[$y] . "%";
    $keywords_name[$y] = preg_replace('/@{2,}/','-',$keywords_name[$y] );
    $stmt2a->bindParam(':search_name' . $y, $keywords_name[$y]);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I have to run the above 2 blocks on 4 different sections on the page for various reasons.

Each time I have to copy in that big block of code for each field I am searching against.

I wondered if it would be possible to create a function instead? The last two blocks of code are very similar - it's just the suffix at the end is different:

e.g.

1. sql_str_unicode vs sql_str_name
2. keywords_unicode vs keywords_name
3. totalKeywords_unicode vs totalKeywords_name

The other thing different each time I use the blocks of code is the `$stmt2a` bit as the bindParams are being used in different blocks of SQL.

I am probably "asking for the moon on a stick" here since I know my code is incredibly long-winded and not very intelligently written and I can see there is a lot of scope for improvement.

In this case I can see having a function for building these dynamic PDO bindParam lines, but I have no idea where to start. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should be able to put all this code into a function. What's the problem? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895) for a more general way to build the WHERE clause dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - I'll ccheck out your suggestion. I was struggling to know which direction to take - the problem is that I am not a very smart programmer, so wasn't sure how to proceed. Thanks for the advice.