# How to filter data that contain specific letter in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table `pub`, it looks like below table:

```
+------------+----------------------------------+
| pub_id     | pub_name                         |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| P0010101   | Jex Max Publication              |
| P0020101   | BPP Publication                  |
| H0030102   | New Harrold Publication          |
| H0040101   | Ultra Press Inc.                 |
| P0050101   | Mountain Publication             |
| P0060103   | Summer Night Publication         |
| P0070104   | Pieterson Grp. of Publishers     |
| P0080102   | Novel Publisher Ltd.             |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to filter with `AND` clause where if in column `pub_id` contain `P0` at the **1st to 2nd** letter and `0101` at the **3rd to 6th** letter from the whole sentences.

I have tried:

```
SELECT pub_id, pub_name FROM pub WHERE LEFT(pub_id,2) = 'P0' and pub_id LIKE '%0101%'
```

but the result is like this

```
+------------+----------------------------------+
| pub_id     | pub_name                         |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| P0010101   | Jex Max Publication              |
| P0020101   | BPP Publication                  |
| P0050101   | Mountain Publication             |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

What i expect for the result was like below:

```
+------------+----------------------------------+
| pub_id     | pub_name                         |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| P0010101   | Jex Max Publication              |
+------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why cant you use MID function? I think you mean letters not word

Comment: @SirajK yes i mean like that

Comment: i forgot that..

Comment: Isn't this just `LEFT(pub_id, 6) = 'P00101'`? Why split it into two different tests?

Comment: Consider storing the P0 separately from the 101

Comment: @Barmar i have some condition that i just need to filter from the first and second letter only , but  sometimes i need to be more specific with the filter so i made the second clause using the third and the sixth letter

Comment: If you're creating the query dynamically, you can have it choose whether to do `LEFT(pub_id, 2)` or `LEFT(pub_id, 6)` depending on which condition it is.

Comment: @Barmar how do i add the word `AND` if i create the query dynamically in php if i want more than two where clause ?

Comment: @Gagantous: You simply add it to the string that's your query. For a more specific answer I guess we need to see some of your PHP code. But consider to ask this in a new question as it seems distinct to the problem here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for a general way to build WHERE clauses dynamically in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `pub_id LIKE 'P00101%'`. You won't need the `left()` then.

[Documentation on `LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: Why do you have `__` in the second version?

Comment: i have the same question too

Comment: @Barmar: Because I got confused by the example. You're right, that was nonsense. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @Gagantous: See above.

Comment: @stickybit please see my comment, in my question comment section