# Is it better to have case statements in where clause or construct a dynamic query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am constructing a query to search results joining multiple tables with millions of records. Db is mysql.

Though my join conditions to the tables remain same always, my where clause statements depend really on the parameters chosen by user from UI.

Case1:

```
   WHERE table.column1 = something 
   AND
   table.column2 = CASE WHEN condition1 = 0 THEN table.column 
                          ELSE condition1 END
```

Case2: construct a dynamic query which appends the AND condition depending on the search criteria.

Case1 looks like taking more time to me. Can any of you suggest which one to take or is there any other better way to deal with dynamic conditions in where.

thanks for the help.

Comment: In most of cases, it is better to avoid "OR" in where clause. If you can build dynamic query without OR and CASE, if will work faster

Comment: I don't think your where condition is as bad as you think it is. It can be rewritten to: `WHERE table.column = something AND table2.column = COALESCE(NULLIF(condition1, 0), table.Column)` which seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: What is `condition1`? Is it a literal that's replaced by the application generating the query from the UI? If so, the SQL engine will evaluate the condition when it's parsing the query, so there shouldn't be any performance impact.

Comment: You might want to look at `https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895` for an elegant way to build the `WHERE` clause dynamically in PHP. You can probably adapt it to other languages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical logic would be not use `case`, just boolean logic:

```
WHERE table.column1 = something  AND
      (@condition1 = 0 OR table.column2 = @condition1)
```

(And `IS NULL` might often be used instead of `= 0` for the "all" scenario.)

Is this better or worse than dynamic SQL?  Basically, this is a question about performance.  If you have an index on only `(column1)`, then it will be used for either a dynamic query or one using boolean (or `case`) logic.  It doesn't matter.

However, if you have an index on `(column1, column2)`, then the above will probably not use the index.  The equivalent version using dynamic SQL *would* use the index, so the *execution* of the query would be faster -- when you are not selecting all the values.

Against this, you need to balance compiling the query.  That usually takes some time, but not much.  If milliseconds matter, then compiling matters.  If tens of seconds matter, then probably not.

So, there are different things that you need to balance.  It is not unusual for dynamic SQL to be the better performing option, particularly when there are multiple conditions.