# Check if multiple values are duplicated php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to check if the `username` is already used, and I need to do it with 4 more fields.

```
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $q2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
    $q2->execute(array($username));
    $result = $q2->fetchAll();

    if (count($result) > 0) {
        $usernameError = 'O utilizador já existe!';
    } 
    else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,role) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
        $q->execute(array($username,$password,$role)); 
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    Database::disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Just add an extra clause using `AND|OR`.

Comment: I've already tried that, but that way it will generate the error for the 5 fields, even if just one of then is duplicated

Comment: @CarlosSantiago: *What* did you try and *specifically* how did it fail?  If you need to check 5 fields in your `WHERE` clause then `AND` and/or `OR` are indeed the keywords you're looking for.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Assuming username is unique in that table, why not just try the insert and tell them the username is taken if the insert fails?

Comment: What do you mean by "need to do it with 4 more fields"?

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's what it's currently doing

Comment: If you want to check if ALL the fields are duplicated in the same record, use `AND`: `username = ? AND field1 = ? AND field2 = ? ...`

Comment: I've already tried with the `SELECT` but that way if just one of the fields are duplicated all the other ones will give an error too! because where I have `usernameError` I will need to add `emailError` and so on

Comment: If any of the fields match - check the returned record for which field is a match.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know which fields are already duplicated, use something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(username = :username) AS usernameError, MAX(email = :email) AS emailError, MAX(phone = :phone) AS phoneError
FROM users
WHERE username = :username OR email = :email or phone = :phone
```

You can then generate appropriate error messages for each of the columns in the result that's equal to `1`.

Comment: No man, it can be only one field, or two, or three, or four, or five, it will depend of the user input, that's why I'm saying that I've already tried put all the fields inside one query and if just one of the fields are duplicated all the other ones will generate the error too even if they aren't duplicated

Comment: you can build the query dynamically based on the input. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895.

Comment: This query won't generate errors about non-duplicated fields. If only username is duplicated, you'll get `usernameError = 1, emailError = 0, phoneError = 0`.