# Condition in mysqli query to change where condition from column1 to column2 for perticular row

Tags: mysql

This code is for example I will add code for SQL injection before applying.

My Table:

```
Example : book_master
|id |name   |regular_price  |special_price
|1  |book1  |100            |80             
|2  |book2  |160            |0
|3  |book3  |200            |150    
|4  |book4  |300            |0
|5  |book5  |450            |320
```

Right now my filter works on regular_price

```
$get_books_sql = "SELECT * FROM books_master";

Filter : 1
if(isset($_GET['from'])){
    $from = $_GET['from'];
    $get_books_sql .= " WHERE regular_price >= $from";
}

Filter : 2
if(isset($_GET['to'])){
    $to = $_GET['to'];
    $get_books_sql .= " WHERE regular_price <= $to";
}
$get_book_result = $conn->query($get_books_sql);
```

I want to add condition for special_price like if special_price > 0 so filter 1 and 2 should apply on special_price if not than filter 1 and 2 applies for regular price for perticular row.

Note    :     I am going to add extra filters after that like category, asc and desc

```
For example : If $_GET['from'] = 60 and $_GET['to'] = 160 so result should be like:
|id |name   |regular_price  |special_price
|1  |book1  |100            |80             
|2  |book2  |160            |0
|3  |book3  |200            |150
```

I am also adding asc desc on that column.
Thank you.

Comment: You should use prepared statements with `bind_param` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: What is the issue? Can you explain more.

Comment: @Barmar sure i am adding code for sql injection.

Comment: @Rocx I want to add condition for special_price like if special_price > 0 so filter 1 and 2 should apply on special_price if not than filter 1 and 2 applies for regular_price for perticular row.

Comment: See COALESCE() and/or CASE

Comment: By looking at your code I think you are creating the query dynamically and then applying them in mysql. Can't you just add a extra condition  and create the query like If/Else.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for how to build WHERE clause dynamically. It uses PDO, which is more convenient for things like this.

Comment: @Rocx yes but i have to apply if/else statement  in query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for both, regular and special price, if special price is present, you can use `OR` and both checks as operands. In the operand checking the special price also check if the special price exists.

```
...
WHERE special_price > 0
      AND special_price BETWEEN ?
                                AND ?
       OR regular_price BETWEEN ?
                                AND ?
...
```

If you want regular price to be ignored, when a special price is present, extend the second operand to also check for the non existence of the special price.

```
...
WHERE special_price > 0
      AND special_price BETWEEN ?
                                AND ?
       OR special_price = 0
          AND regular_price BETWEEN ?
                                    AND ?
...
```

Note that if the special price doesn't exist, that would be better expressed by setting `special_price` to `NULL` rather than `0`. And yes, you should use parameterized queries -- **right away**!