# How to use dynamic conditions in mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Unable to use dynamic conditions in stored procedure.The following sample code is giving error.

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@id_filter;

END' at line 8

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sample`(IN wid INT)

BEGIN
DECLARE id_filter text DEFAULT '';
IF wid > 0 THEN
     SET @id_filter = CONCAT(' Where id= ',wid);
END IF ;
SELECT * from users @id_filter;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PREPARE` to create dynamic SQL.

```
PREPARE @stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT * FROM users ', @id_filter);
EXECUTE @stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE @stmt;
```

Comment: I need to implement this with a very large query with multiple conditions. For every conditions creating a new query will make very complex code. Do we have any other option?

Comment: Do you have to do this in a stored procedure? A programming language like PHP or Python is more suited to generating queries from complex condition data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for example.

Comment: Trying to reduce the execution time.

Comment: I don't think it will make a significant difference whether you generate the dynamic SQL on the client or in the server.

Comment: Since there are no dynamic data structures like arrays in SQL stored procedures, handling complex combinations will be difficult.