# Prepared statement when the SQL statement is not the same all the time

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I have the following code, the SQL statement is changing depending on what options the user chooses in a form.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

if ($valueone !== "all") {
    $sql .= " WHERE brand = ? ";
}
if ($valuetwo !== "all") {
    if (strpos($sql, "WHERE") !== false) { 
        $sql .= " AND category = ? ";
    } 
    else {
        $sql .= " WHERE category = ? ";
    }
}
if ($valuethree !== "all") {
    if (strpos($sql, "WHERE") !== false) { 
        $sql .= " AND third = ? ";
    } 
    else {
        $sql .= " WHERE third = ? ";
    }
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY rand();";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("location: error.php?sql");
    die(); 
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $valueone, $valuetwo, $valuethree);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Now, I obviously want to protect myself with prepared statements, but how would I go about this? Since it won't be three "S" all the time, sometimes not at all.

I hope you can see what I am trying to do!

Comment: It's easier if you use PDO. Then you can easily bind the parameters dynamically.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909923/1491895 for how to do it with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding "sss" you could build that along with the sql. As an example

```
if ($valueone !== "all") {
    $sql .= " WHERE brand = ? ";
    $types .= "s"
}
```